# Why is casting a const reference directly to a mutable reference invalid in Rust?

Tags: rust

This piece of code is correct:

```
fn f() {
    let mut x = 11;
    b(&x as *const u8 as *mut u8);
}

fn b(x: *mut u8) {}
```

Why is `b(&x as *const u8 as *mut u8)` is valid whereas `b(&x as *mut u8)` is invalid? The compiler complains about:

> error[E0606]: casting `&u8` as `*mut u8` is invalid

Answer (score 9):

The superficial answer to the question "why?" is that these simply are the rules of `as` expressions in Rust. Quoting from the [Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/casts.html):

> Casting is not transitive, that is, even if `e as U1 as U2` is a valid
>   expression, `e as U2` is not necessarily so.

With the `as` operator, you can either perform explicit [*coercions*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html) or [*casts*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/casts.html).

There is neither a cast nor a coercion to go directly from `&u8` to `*mut u8`. However, there is a *pointer weakening coercion* from `&T` to `*const T` and a *cast* from a pointer to a sized type to any other. The combination of the two results in the expression in your question.

The deeper question is why the language was designed this way. I don't actually know, since I wasn't in the room when these decisions were made, and I couldn't find a rationale on the web. Rust in general tries to be very explicit with type casts, to avoid conversions that weren't actually intended and to keep the rules simple. These princilpes seem to have influenced this particular design decision as well.

Comment: This is what I ended up having to do, it makes sense, but seems silly at first...    let ptr: *mut u8 = &op_create as *const control_operation as *const u8 as *mut u8;

Comment: @stu If you want to save some typing, and some irrelevant noise for people reading the code, you should also be able to use `&op_create as *const _ as *const _ as *mut u8`.

Comment: interesting, it doesn't care what type you're coercing or casting to, just that you're casting to the const vs mut of it. neato thanks.

Comment: The underscore tells the compiler to infer the type. There is only one valid type for each of these underscores, so we don't need to spell it out.

Answer (score 0):

Because a rust reference is constant.

What you want to do is to cast a mutable reference `&mut x` to a raw integer mutable pointer `*mut i32`.

This code is valid:

```
let mut x = 42;
let ptr = &mut x as *mut _;
// equivalent to
let ptr_2 = &x as *const _ as *mut _;
```